# How do you circumvent repeated keydown messages when you want to use them with javascript where you hold the key down but want it only to play once?

Tags: javascript, dom, keypress

I have a piece of code that looks something like below and it works fine. What it does is it launches an oscillator sound when the mouse clicks on a div named synth.It then stops playing the oscillator when the mouse button is released.

```
 synth.onmousedown= function () {
    oscillator = context.createOscillator(),  // Creates the oscillator 
    oscillator.type = synthWaveform.value;  
    oscillator.frequency.value = pitchInput.value;                   
    oscillator.connect(context.destination);  // Connects it to output
    oscillator.noteOn(0); 


    };



    synth.onmouseup = function ()    {  
    oscillator.disconnect(); 

    };
```

I then added the code below so that when a user presses a keyboard charachter it triggers the oscillator. The problem is that when the key is held down it repeadedly plays and then won't stop when the keyboard character is released. I want to know if there are any libraries or code that can be used to circumvent this. The goal is to have the end result be like a mousedown/up effect but with keyboard movements triggering the sound.Thank you.

```
$('body').keydown(function() {
oscillator = context.createOscillator(),  // Creates the oscillator 
oscillator.type = synthWaveform.value;  
oscillator.frequency.value = pitchInput.value;                   
oscillator.connect(context.destination);  // Connects it to output
oscillator.noteOn(0); 
});

$('body').keyup(function() {
oscillator.disconnect();

});
```

Comment: you want your function to execute for only one time?

Comment: If you want to look at it like that. I guess you could say I want the function to launch one time.... as long as the key is held down. So I guess the logic would be for it to only launch once until it recognizes a keyup function, but not play again until another keydown event happens.

Comment: Use a `keyup` handler instead?

Comment: Are you sure your `$('body').keyup` event is firing ?

Comment: see my answer below! it may help you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use underscore.js debounce if you need something fancier than the below option.

```
var keydown = false;

$('body').keydown(function() {
    if(!keydown){
        oscillator = context.createOscillator(),  // Creates the oscillator 
        oscillator.type = synthWaveform.value;  
        oscillator.frequency.value = pitchInput.value;                   
        oscillator.connect(context.destination);  // Connects it to output
        oscillator.noteOn(0);
        keydown = true;
    }
});

$('body').keyup(function() {
    oscillator.disconnect();
    keydown = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a workaround

```
var keyIsDown = false;

$('body').keydown(function() {
    if(keyIsDown) {
       // key is already down
       return true;
    }

    keyIsDown = true;

    // do your keydown handler
}

$('body').keyup(function() {
    keyIsDown = false;
}
```

Comment: returning false in an even could prevent the default action on other events assigned to the body.