# How to play sound only once while holding a keyboard button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

Recently I have create a simple code using JavaScript. Basically, it a press to play sound program. The sounds are 3-4 seconds long. Everything worked fine until I found out that if I hold down a key the sound would play itself repeatedly. They didn't finished their length, but keep restart to play at the beginning. All I want is just that it play to the end and stop, and will play again if the key is up and press again.

This is my code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <audio id="fart" source src="" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var player = document.getElementById("fart");
        //var keyIsDown = true;

        var getCommand = function (pressedChar) {
            var command = null;
            if (keyIsDown) {
                switch (pressedChar) {
                    case 'a':
                        //alert("I'm A.");
                        player.setAttribute("src", "1fart-07 C7.mp3");
                        player.play();
                        //keyIsDown = false;
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                        player.setAttribute("src", "2fart-05 D7.mp3");
                        player.play();
                        break;
                    case 'c':
                        player.setAttribute("src", "3fart-01 E7.mp3");
                        player.play();
                        break;
                    case 'd':
                        player.setAttribute("src", "4fart-03 F7.mp3");
                        player.play();
                        break;
                    case 'e':
                        player.setAttribute("src", "5fart Na G7.mp3");
                        player.play();
                        break;
                    case 'f':
                        player.setAttribute("src", "6fart Na A7.mp3");
                        player.play();
                        break;
                    case 'g':
                        player.setAttribute("src", "7fart Na B7.mp3");
                        player.play();
                        break;
                    case 'h':
                        player.setAttribute("src", "fart-07 C8.mp3");
                        player.play();
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("OUT");
                        break;
                }
                return command;
            } else {
                command = null;
            }
        };
        /////
        /*$(document).keyup(function(e){
         keyIsDown = true;
         });*/

        //////
        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            var pressedChar = String.fromCharCode(code).toLowerCase();
            var command = getCommand(pressedChar);
            keyIsDown = true;
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("ready!");
        });
        ///////
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've googled and found [this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301728/how-do-you-circumvent-repeated-keydown-messages-when-you-want-to-use-them-with-j) so I tried to adapt it to mine, but still didn't work out. Anyone has any suggestion? I also found a way in [Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335577/html5-audio-sound-only-plays-once), but didn't work. I feel like now I'm getting close to the answer, but may be I code something wrong. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: what happens when you have multiple keys pressed?

Comment: You can try to use the ended property to see if the current clip has ended. If it has, play another sound, if it hasn't, do nothing.

Comment: @JoeSwindell Thx. I have worked out on that way of function. But 'ended' didn't work, instead it was 'paused'. 
----

Comment: @CayceK When pressed multiple keys, the key that was the last one will play the sound. It won't play 2 sounds in the same time.

Comment: ok. YOu state you found out what to do. You should post an answer so if someone needs help with a similar situation your question might help theml

Comment: @CayceK I know.. I know.. last time I was busy. I've come back and post the answer, you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is here...
1)create a variable for the key you use each one and set to true, like var q = true; at the beginning. 
2) create a function to detect if the keyboard button is up, by using the same variable of the keyDown function. Then, set the variable that u have setup in (1) to be true.

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    console.log("One of the keys is up");
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var pressedChar = String.fromCharCode(code).toLowerCase();
    switch (pressedChar) {
        case'q':
            q = true;
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Nothing");
    }
});
```

3) in the main function that play the music, give if-else function inside the switch case to detect if the key is still pressing. After play(); set the variable to be false;

```
case 'q':
    if (q) {
        //alert("I'm A.");
        player.setAttribute("src", "1fart-07 C7.mp3");
        player.play();
        q = false;
    } else {
        command = null;
        console.log("q is holded"); // if the keyboard is pressed before it will be here. 
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace every `player.play();` with `player.stop().play();`

Comment: I have found my way to do what I want, but your answer still interests me. What happen when you put two of (); like that? will it stop and never play again?--and what if it is player.play().stop();? I will try this when I'm free, but it would be appreciated if you can tell me.  :D Thx anyway.

Comment: Adding `.stop()` before `.play()` would stop any animations that are in progress previously.